# MongoDB / Mongoose: is there a way to query for a value within a field that is an object that contains two arrays?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

At this moment I am using 2 queries to search for a username value inside a field that is an object that contains 2 arrays then merging them together. I can't seem to figure out how to write a query that would search through both arrays at once and return all results that match a given `username` in any of the arrays. I was wondering if this is even possible? Thanks for any inputs!

```
Game.find({
    active: false,
    'current_players.team1': { $elemMatch: { $in: [username] } }
})

Game.find({
    active: false,
    'current_players.team2': { $elemMatch: { $in: [username] } }
})
```

This is the schema I am working with:

```
var Game = mongoose.Schema({ 
    id: ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    current_players: {
        team1: Array        // [ 'jim', 'bob', 'sarah', null ]
        team2: Array        // [ 'peter', 'frank', null, 'simon']
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To search both arrays in one query for this problem you can use the $or operator.

```
db.collection.find({
"active": false,
$or: [
  {
    "current_players.team1": "username"
  },
  {
    "current_players.team2": "username"
  }
]
```

})

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This method only returns one result. I was looking for a method to return all results that match.